# How to display calendar view in period selector of amcharts?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, amcharts

I'm using  Javascript Stock Chart from amcharts. I want a dropdown calendar view in click of period selector input field. Please can anyone help me how can I make drop-down calendar in from and to fields here?[image: I need to make dropdown calendar in from and to fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3094124 : Hi, I am using same code it works for me,
Here is my script for amChart, first check if it shows alert on changed or not and you have to use `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>` jquery ui liabrary.
`

```
     AmCharts.ready(function() {
        var chart = new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
        chart.pathToImages = "/amcharts/amcharts/images/";

        var dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet.dataProvider = chartDataS;
        dataSet.fieldMappings = [{fromField:"val", toField:"value"}];
        dataSet.categoryField = "date";
        chart.dataSets = [dataSet];

        var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
        chart.panels = [stockPanel];

        var legend = new AmCharts.StockLegend();
        stockPanel.stockLegend = legend;

        var panelsSettings = new AmCharts.PanelsSettings();
        panelsSettings.startDuration = 5;
        chart.panelsSettings = panelsSettings;

        var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph.valueField = "value";
        graph.type = "column";
        graph.title = "Users ";
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);

        var categoryAxesSettings = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
        categoryAxesSettings.dashLength = 1;
        chart.categoryAxesSettings = categoryAxesSettings;

        var valueAxesSettings = new AmCharts.ValueAxesSettings();
        valueAxesSettings .dashLength = 1;
        chart.valueAxesSettings  = valueAxesSettings;

        var chartScrollbarSettings = new AmCharts.ChartScrollbarSettings();
        chartScrollbarSettings.graph = graph;
        chartScrollbarSettings.graphType = "line";
        chart.chartScrollbarSettings = chartScrollbarSettings;

        var chartCursorSettings = new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
        chartCursorSettings.valueBalloonsEnabled = true;
        //chartCursorSettings.fullWidth = true;
        chart.chartCursorSettings = chartCursorSettings;

        var periodSelector = new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
        periodSelector.periods = [{period:"DD", count:1, label:"1 day"},
            {period:"DD", selected:true, count:5, label:"5 days"},
            {period:"MM", count:1, label:"1 month"},
            {period:"YYYY", count:1, label:"1 year"},
            {period:"YTD", label:"YTD"},
            {period:"MAX", label:"MAX",selected:true}];
        periodSelector.position = "top";
        chart.periodSelector = periodSelector;

        /*chart.periodSelector.addListener('changed', function(){
         alert('changed');
         $( ".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" ).datepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
         });
         });*/

        chart.addListener('rendered' ,function (event){

            $( ".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                //minDate: newStartDate,
                //maxDate: newEndDate,
                onClose: function() {
                    $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" ).trigger('blur');
                }
            });
        });


        chart.write("StockChartDiv");


    });
```

`

Comment: It shows an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker' " while using as the above script, I have included jquery-ui.js library too

Comment: use the following link

 `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: The above code works only if I have single panel but I have three panels in single graph so if I put addListener it doesn't display two lower graph panels

Answer (score 1):

Add this code , it will help you

```
            chart.addListener('rendered' ,function (event){ 
            $( ".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                //minDate: newStartDate,
                //maxDate: newEndDate,
                onClose: function() {
                    $(".amChartsPeriodSelector .amChartsInputField" ).trigger('blur');
                }
            });
        });
```

`

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use JQUERY UI Date picker.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Here are few more good calenders, meet your needs, with good tutorial & docs-

2.http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

3.http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/

Here is another list of useful calendars-

http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-jquery-calendar-and-date-picker-plugins-for-web-designers/